# replace new line with space only if it isn't followed by another new line (undo hard wrap in text)

Tags: python, regex, sed

I have a bunch of text files with hard line wraps (i.e. new line at around 80 chars). I'd like to undo that and join all of those sentences together but maintain new lines where they are new chapters or paragraphs.

i.e I.d like to replace '\n' with ' ' if and only if the following character is not another '\n'

The following python code does what I want, but not very efficiently, and I'd rather do it with regex and/or sed.

```
s = open(filename, 'r').read()
p = s.split('\n\n') # split into paragraphs
p = [x.replace('\n', ' ') for x in p] # iterate all paragraphs, replace \n
s2 = '\n\n'.join(p) # join paragraphs back together
```

e.g.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Vivamus porta dui quis aliquet interdum. Sed
in pellentesque libero. Quisque tempus nisl nec
nisl condimentum ullamcorper.

Mauris vulputate nibh nec ipsum mattis rutrum.
Nunc nec tristique magna, non sagittis lacus.
Aliquam id urna lectus.

Maecenas volutpat libero quis erat mollis, et
aliquet purus dignissim. Sed faucibus, lectus in
auctor ornare, dolor libero ultrices sem, vel
iaculis ex nulla quis lacus.
```

Should become:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta dui quis aliquet interdum. Sed in pellentesque libero. Quisque tempus nisl nec nisl condimentum ullamcorper.

Mauris vulputate nibh nec ipsum mattis rutrum. Nunc nec tristique magna, non sagittis lacus. Aliquam id urna lectus.

Maecenas volutpat libero quis erat mollis, et aliquet purus dignissim. Sed faucibus, lectus in auctor ornare, dolor libero ultrices sem, vel iaculis ex nulla quis lacus.
```

---

**Update**

I've tried and timed the 5 python methods below on a 5MB text file. I'm surprised to see that all 3 regex methods were an order of magnitude slower than the python split/replace/join method.

```
def m1(s):
    p = s.split('\n\n') # split into paragraphs
    p = [x.replace('\n', ' ') for x in p] # iterate all paragraphs, replace \n
    r = '\n\n'.join(p) # join paragraphs back together
    return r

def m2(s):
    r = re.sub(r"(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)", " ", s)
    return r

def m3(s):
    p = re.compile(ur'(?<!^)\n(?=\S)', re.MULTILINE)
    r = re.sub(p, u" ", s)
    return r

def m4(s):
    r = "".join(["".join(v) if k else " ".join(map(str.strip, v))+"\n"  for k, v in groupby(s, str.isspace)])
    return r


def repl(m):
    return (' ' if len(m.group(1))==1 else m.group(1)) + m.group(2)
def m5(s):
    r = re.sub(r'(\n+)(.)', repl, s)
    return r
```

results:

```
np.array( timeit.repeat('r=m1(s)', 'from __main__ import *', repeat=5, number=N) )/N
Out[4]: array([ 0.01343679,  0.0136183 ,  0.0153013 ,  0.0122381 ,  0.01205051])

np.array( timeit.repeat('r=m2(s)', 'from __main__ import *', repeat=5, number=N) )/N
Out[5]: array([ 0.10881839,  0.108728  ,  0.10904381,  0.10862441,  0.10867569])

np.array( timeit.repeat('r=m3(s)', 'from __main__ import *', repeat=5, number=N) )/N
Out[6]: array([ 0.1358021 ,  0.1352592 ,  0.13556101,  0.1357465 ,  0.1354876 ])

np.array( timeit.repeat('r=m4(s)', 'from __main__ import *', repeat=5, number=N) )/N
Out[7]: array([ 2.51403842,  2.37821078,  2.4169096 ,  2.56688828,  2.36240571])

np.array( timeit.repeat('r=m5(s)', 'from __main__ import *', repeat=5, number=N) )/N
Out[8]: array([ 0.16381941,  0.1616353 ,  0.1620033 ,  0.1617353 ,  0.1615443 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub) and then you have to play around with negative 
look-behind and look-ahead assertations. If your input is large this will not be very efficient.

The look-behind:

```
(?<!...)
     Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded by a match for .... This is called a negative lookbehind assertion. Similar to positive lookbehind assertions, the contained pattern must only match strings of some fixed length. Patterns which start with negative lookbehind assertions may match at the beginning of the string being searched.
```

The look-ahead:

```
(?!...)
     Matches if ... doesn’t match next. This is a negative lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?!Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if
 it’s not followed by 'Asimov'.
```

Here's an example:

```
>>> text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Vivamus porta dui quis aliquet interdum. Sed
in pellentesque libero. Quisque tempus nisl nec
nisl condimentum ullamcorper.

Mauris vulputate nibh nec ipsum mattis rutrum.
Nunc nec tristique magna, non sagittis lacus.
Aliquam id urna lectus.

Maecenas volutpat libero quis erat mollis, et
aliquet purus dignissim. Sed faucibus, lectus in
auctor ornare, dolor libero ultrices sem, vel
iaculis ex nulla quis lacus."""

>>> re.sub(r"(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)", " ", text)
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta dui quis aliquet interdum. Sed in pellentesque libero. Quisque tempus nisl nec nisl condimentum ullamcorper.\n\nMauris vulputate nibh nec ipsum mattis rutrum. Nunc nec tristique magna, non sagittis lacus. Aliquam id urna lectus.\n\nMaecenas volutpat libero quis erat mollis, et aliquet purus dignissim. Sed faucibus, lectus in auctor ornare, dolor libero ultrices sem, vel iaculis ex nulla quis lacus.'

>>> print(_)
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta dui quis aliquet interdum. Sed in pellentesque libero. Quisque tempus nisl nec nisl condimentum ullamcorper.

Mauris vulputate nibh nec ipsum mattis rutrum. Nunc nec tristique magna, non sagittis lacus. Aliquam id urna lectus.

Maecenas volutpat libero quis erat mollis, et aliquet purus dignissim. Sed faucibus, lectus in auctor ornare, dolor libero ultrices sem, vel iaculis ex nulla quis lacus.
```

Comment: thanks. not sure why this got a -ve vote. It worked for me. Though I had to use a space instead of just "" otherwise the adjacent words would be stuck together (in your example see adipiscingelit. re.sub("\n(?!\n)", " ", text)

Comment: I've not down voted but this won't preserve the paragraphs.

Comment: It actually did preserve my paragraphs.

Comment: @memo according to your output the space between two lines should be preserved which is not met here

Comment: ah yes. just realized that. It preserves paragraphs (i.e. new lines between chunks of text), but reduces from 2 new lines to 1 (or from 3 new lines to 2) etc.

Comment: Also it doesn't preserve the space between `adipiscing` and `elit`

Comment: @memo sorry, fixed it. I'm not sure if you want to do this on a large piece of text though.

Comment: thanks. I tried it on a 5MB txt file and it took 0.16secs, so it's ok. Though my ghetto python split/join method took 0.02secs, so maybe regex isn't the most efficient way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for that, like this:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' RS='' ORS='\n\n' OFS=' ' file
```

Explanation:

- `{$1=$1}` looks like it won't changed anything. That's true, but still `awk` will reassemble the record using the new separators (look below)
- `1` always evaluates to true, since no action has been specified, awk will print the whole current record
- `RS=''` is in *input record separator*. The empty string is a special value for it. It means split records by an empty line and fields by new lines.
- `ORS='\n\n'` set's the *output record separator* also to a blank line.
- `OFS=' '` set's the *output field separator* to a space.

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta dui quis aliquet interdum. Sed in pellentesque libero. Quisque tempus nisl nec nisl condimentum ullamcorper.

Mauris vulputate nibh nec ipsum mattis rutrum. Nunc nec tristique magna, non sagittis lacus. Aliquam id urna lectus.

Maecenas volutpat libero quis erat mollis, et aliquet purus dignissim. Sed faucibus, lectus in auctor ornare, dolor libero ultrices sem, vel iaculis ex nulla quis lacus.
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about awk. Will check it out. Looks very useful for other things too.

Comment: Yeah. Plus it is damn fast compared to the regex solutions

Answer (score 0):

You could use a groupby, grouping on whitespace:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("test.txt") as f:
    print("".join(["".join(v) if k else " ".join(map(str.strip, v))+"\n"  for k, v in groupby(f, str.isspace)]))
```

Which would give you:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta dui quis aliquet interdum. Sed in pellentesque libero. Quisque tempus nisl nec nisl condimentum ullamcorper.

Mauris vulputate nibh nec ipsum mattis rutrum. Nunc nec tristique magna, non sagittis lacus. Aliquam id urna lectus.

Maecenas volutpat libero quis erat mollis, et aliquet purus dignissim. Sed faucibus, lectus in auctor ornare, dolor libero ultrices sem, vel iaculis ex nulla quis lacus.
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about groupby, though it performed considerably slower than split/replace/join.

Comment: @memo, groupy happens at the c level so it is pretty efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try following regex in python:

Assuming `text` variable contains your sample text

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<!^)\n(?=\S)', re.MULTILINE)

result = re.sub(p, u" ", text)
print(result)
```

It will print following text, replacing single newline with space.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta dui quis aliquet interdum. Sed in pellentesque libero. Quisque tempus nisl nec nisl condimentum ullamcorper.

Mauris vulputate nibh nec ipsum mattis rutrum. Nunc nec tristique magna, non sagittis lacus. Aliquam id urna lectus.

Maecenas volutpat libero quis erat mollis, et aliquet purus dignissim. Sed faucibus, lectus in auctor ornare, dolor libero ultrices sem, vel iaculis ex nulla quis lacus.
```

See demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oS5uJ0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes complicated replacements can be accomplished by passing a function in as the 2nd parameter to `re.sub()`.

```
import re

ipsum = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Vivamus porta dui quis aliquet interdum. Sed
in pellentesque libero. Quisque tempus nisl nec
nisl condimentum ullamcorper.

Mauris vulputate nibh nec ipsum mattis rutrum.
Nunc nec tristique magna, non sagittis lacus.
Aliquam id urna lectus.

Maecenas volutpat libero quis erat mollis, et
aliquet purus dignissim. Sed faucibus, lectus in
auctor ornare, dolor libero ultrices sem, vel
iaculis ex nulla quis lacus.
'''

ipsum = re.sub(
    r'(\n+)(?=.)',
    lambda m: ' ' if len(m.group(1))==1 else m.group(1),
    ipsum)

print ipsum
```